# Variable placeholders in a char *

Tags: c

I have the following `C` example:

```
char *message;
char *name = "John";
int age = 100;

message = "Hello, I am John, age 100";
```

How to put `name` and `age` as parameters in `message`?

Pseudo code`message = "Hello, I am {name}, age {age}"`

***UPDATE***

I tried the following example from comments:

```
char *body = "{ \"capabilities\": {},\"desiredCapabilities\": {}}";
int content_length = sizeof(body);

char *format = "POST /session HTTP/1.1\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nContent-Length:%d\r\n\r\n%s";
int len = snprintf(NULL, 0, format, content_length, body);
char *message = malloc(len + 1);
snprintf(message, len + 1, format, content_length, body);
```

But I am getting error at `char *message = malloc(len + 1);`:

`error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]|`

Comment: C or C++?  Also, if C++ can you use `std::string`?

Comment: Use `std::string` instead. Then you can use `+` operators and `std::to_string`.

Comment: I updated the question. It is about `C`

Comment: Just char *name = "John"; should give a warning because it is a char const *

Comment: If in C, do you know how to output it with `printf`? Have you heard about [`sprintf` (or the more preferred `snprintf`)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)?

Comment: @AntoineMorrier Not invalid in C unfortunately, IIRC one has to enable extra warnings for that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude could you please give me a specific example of my case, because I tried with `sprintf` but since `*message` is immutable, it threw `segmentation fault`

Comment: `message` isn't immutable, it's an uninitialised pointer that doesn't point anywhere valid. Make message a char buffer, e.g. `char message[80];` and use that. And use `snprintf` instead of `sprintf` to prevent buffer overflow.

Comment: No `message` (or `*message`) is immutable, instead it's *not initialized* which means the contents of `message` is *indeterminate* if it's a local variable inside a function (and a null pointer if defined globally) and attempting to dereference that pointer (which `sprintf` and the related `snprintf` does) leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: And if you don't know about the uninitialized status of local variable, or how to allocate memory dynamically, then I suggest you take a couple of steps back, and [find a couple of good beginners books to read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), and start over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with the `snprintf`.  This works like `printf`, but puts the result into a string instead of writing it to `stdout`.

```
char message[100];
snprintf(message, sizeof(message), "Hello, I am %s, age %d", name, age);
```

Note that this example uses a fixed size buffer.  If you want to dynamically allocate the space, you could do this:

```
const char *format = "Hello, I am %s, age %d";
int len = strlen(format) + strlen(name) + sizeof(age)*3 + 1;
char *message = malloc(len);
snprintf(message, len, "Hello, I am %s, age %d", name, age);
// ...
free(message);
```

This sets aside space for the format string, each parameter, and the terminating null byte.

Another way of getting the needed length is to call `snprintf` twice, the first time with `NULL` for the string and 0 for the size.  The return value is the length of the resulting string:

```
const char *format = "Hello, I am %s, age %d";
int len = snprintf(NULL, 0, "Hello, I am %s, age %d", name, age);
char *message = malloc(len + 1);
snprintf(message, len + 1, "Hello, I am %s, age %d", name, age);
// ...
free(message);
```

Regarding the error in your updated code, you're apparently using a C++ compiler instead of a C compiler.  If you're writing C, use a C compiler.

Comment: You don't need the `-1`; `snprintf` accounts for the terminating null.

Comment: Maybe you could say that he could dynamicaly allocate the memory with malloc

Comment: @CuriousGuy: You would have to use `malloc` or `calloc` to set aside the space for the final string and assign the resulting pointer to `message`.

Comment: (As a note: You can do without the handish length calculation and call `len = snprintf(NULL, 0, ...)` to get the required length, excluding the terminating null this time.)

Comment: @MOehm Correct.  Removed the -1 in the initial example and added an example of using `snprintf` to get the length.

Comment: @dbush Could you please take a look at my answer to the question? I wrote an answer because it is too long for a comment.

Comment: @CuriousGuy You're using a C++ compiler instead of a C compiler.

Comment: @dbush, yes, thank you. I changed to `C` compiler and it run. But I have problem with `int content_length = sizeof(body);` as it returns `8`, the size of the pointer, as `chux` commented. How can I get the size of the `body` string itself?

Comment: @CuriousGuy Use `strlen` to get the length of a string.